# Read Semi-Structured Text File

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a text file that contains metadata and file paths for each document set.  Metadata is only assigned at the beginning of the set, but the set may contain one or more documents.  I need to create a CSV or XML output for each document set (each object starts with "BEGIN: ") so I can import into another system.

I have a PS script that is parsing out each object from the text file and creating a delimted string for each object, but I am thinking this is not the most efficient way to parse this data.  Can anyone help guide me in the right direction in parsing this text file and setting up the XML/CSV output correctly?

**POTENTIAL ISSUES**

1. Objects can have one or more user names
2. Objects can have one or more paths for the image file

**SAMPLE TEXT FILE**

```
BEGIN:
DocTypeName: SAMPLE
>>DocDate: 12/11/2008
Reference #: 0001122
User Name: George Washington
User Name: Martha Washington
>>IRRELEVANT DATA 
...
>>FileName: [path]\761019.TIF
>>IRRELEVANT DATA 
...
>>FileName: [path]\761020.TIF
BEGIN:
DocTypeName: SAMPLE
>>DocDate: 12/11/2008
Reference #: 0001123
User Name: Abe Lincoln
>>IRRELEVANT DATA 
...
>>FileName: [path]\761021.TIF
>>IRRELEVANT DATA 
...
>>FileName: [path]\761022.TIF
```

Comment: 1. Where's the existing script? 2. If you're already parsing the text, then you should create objects with properties and use `Export-CSV` without creating your own "csv-string". It's more clean that way. 3. How are you going to handle multiple filepaths and usernames in csv? Any special delimiter in the Username field or are you creating multiple records(usernames*paths=4 in first sample) for the same document?

Answer (score 3):

Does this help you any?

```
Get-Content testfile.txt -Delimiter 'BEGIN:' |
Select -Skip 1 |
foreach {
$DOC = [PSCustomObject]@{
        DocTypeName = $Null
        DocDate = $Null
        Reference = $Null
        UserName = [collections.arraylist]@()
        FileName = [collections.arraylist]@()
        }

Switch -Regex ($_.split("`n"))
 {
   'DocTypeName: (.+)' {$DOC.DocTypeName = $Matches[1];Continue}
   '>>DocDate: (.+)'   {$DOC.DocDate = $Matches[1];Continue}
   'Reference #: (.+)'  {$DOC.Reference = $Matches[1];Continue}
   'User Name: (.+)'  {[void]$DOC.UserName.add($Matches[1]);Continue}
   '>>FileName: (.+)' {[void]$DOC.FileName.add($Matches[1]);Continue}
 }

$DOC
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would import the file splitting on 'BEGIN:' (just like mjolinor), and then run it through a ForEach that would build out an object with Add-Member using whatever properties are in the imported record. If you have any questions about my code please ask.

```
$RawData = Get-Content testfile.txt -Delimiter 'BEGIN:' | Select -Skip 1
$Records = ForEach($Object in $RawData){
    $Record=New-Object PSObject
    $Object.split("`n")|Where{$_ -match "^(?:>>)?(.+?):\s*?(\S.*)?$"}|ForEach{
        If([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($Record.($Matches[1]))){
            Add-Member -InputObject $Record -NotePropertyName $Matches[1] -NotePropertyValue @($Matches[2])
        }Else{
            $Record.($Matches[1])+=$Matches[2]
        }

    }
    $Record
}
```

That leaves you with an array, `$Records`, that has objects with whatever properties were provided by the input file. If all you want are the specific fields then mjolinor's solution would probably be a better option.

Comment: I am testing this code and it looks like it is working fairly well. It does include "BEGIN" for the next record at the end of each array item, but not sure that is a huge deal since I will only be extracting some of the data in each object. I did have to make one change to code to make it run without errors: "Add-Member -InputObject $Record -type NoteProperty -Name $Matches[1] -value @($Matches[2])". I am running through a few more tests, but this already looks better than my text parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI for a new command coming in V5 - ConvertFrom-String. This takes a template that you use to tell the command how to interpret the text e.g.:

```
BEGIN:
DocTypeName: SAMPLE
>>DocDate: 12/11/2008
Reference #: {Reference*:{Number:0001122}
User Name: {UserNames:{UserName*:George Washington}
User Name: {UserName*:Martha Washington}}
>>IRRELEVANT DATA 
...
>>FileName: {Paths:{Path*:[path]\761019.TIF}
>>IRRELEVANT DATA 
...
>>FileName: {Path*:[path]\761020.TIF}}}
BEGIN:
DocTypeName: SAMPLE
>>DocDate: 12/11/2008
Reference #: {Reference*:{Number:0001123}
User Name: {UserNames:{UserName*:Abe Lincoln}}
>>IRRELEVANT DATA 
...
>>FileName: {Paths:{Path*:[path]\761021.TIF}
>>IRRELEVANT DATA 
...
>>FileName: {Path*:[path]\761022.TIF}}}
```

You can then throw the original file content (in variable $content) and access the data like so:

```
$res = $content | cfs -TemplateFile .\template.txt
PS> $res[0].Reference.Number
0001122
PS> $res[0].Reference.UserNames.UserName.value
George Washington
Martha Washington
PS> $res[0].Reference.Paths.Path.value
[path]\761019.TIF
[path]\761020.TIF
```

The use of this command in preview form is a little clunky because it wants to display the `Extent` property by default which I think you only need for debugging the template.